# c++ - passing standard container as a template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl, template-templates

So, I need to make a mixin class that would encapsulate children of some derived class. The derived class should inherit from the mixin while providing a container template as a template template argument for the mixin.

The desired code is somewhat like that:

```
/*template definition*/
template<template<typename T, typename A> class C>
class HasChildren {
  protected:
    C<T, A> m_children;
    /* whatever */
};
```

It has an array of issues:

1. When trying to instantiate this class like `HasChildren<std::vector<int>>`(just for testing), compiler says `expected a class template, got ‘std::vector<int>’`. Clearly, I'm not passing a template template. **I would like to know what exactly I'm trying to pass**.
2. For `C<T, A> m_children;` compiler says that `T` and `A` are out of scope. When I add `typename` keyword for them, the error changes to `error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)`. **I would like to know why `T` and `A` are out of scope and why adding `typename` leads to this error**.

Comment: a template template parameter takes a template, e.g. `std::vector`.  A template parameter takes a type, e.g `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Given that you don't know what to pass to `C<...>`, you probably want just `typename C` instead of a template-template parameter. A template-template parameter would let you pass `std::vector` (w/o element type) into `HasChildren`, then specify the element type when declaring `m_children`, for example. Also, a template-template parameter for a container should have `<typename...>` parameters rather than two `typename`s, lest you want to manually specify the allocator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You pass a type, `std::vector<int>`, instead of a template, `std::vector`.
2. You need to accept the template template parameters too. `template<typename T, typename A>` does not make the template template use `T` and `A`. They are just for documentation and can be removed.

Example:

```cpp
template <template <class, class> class C, class T, class A>
//                                         ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
class HasChildren {
   protected:
    C<T, A> m_children;
};

int main() {
    HasChildren<std::vector, int, std::allocator<int>> hc;
//              ^template^   ^-----parameters-------^
}
```

---

If you prefer to instantiate `HasChildren` like you originally tried, by using `HasChildren<std::vector<int>>`, you can do that by specializing `HasChildren`:

```cpp
template<class> class HasChildren; // primary

// specialization:
template<template <class, class> class C, class T, class A>
class HasChildren<C<T,A>> {
   protected:
    C<T,A> m_children;
};

int main() {
    HasChildren<std::vector<int>> hc; 
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see, thank you! But, just to make it clear, why exactly `T` and `A` are out of scope of `HasChildren`? I thought that template scope ends with the closing brace of its definition, where there is a definition.

Comment: @AntonTretyakov You're welcome. `T` and `A` in your example are not parameters to the template template. They are only there for the readers of the code to make it easier to see what the two template parameters that `C` takes will map to.  `template<template<typename T, typename A> class C>` only has one parameter (the `template C`) even though it may look like 3.

Comment: I mean, I understand that there, in fact, are no `T` and `A` arguments provided with the initial code I wrote. But why these exact errors? `error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)` doesn't seem to fit particularly well to this situation too, if you ask me.

Comment: @AntonTretyakov Do you mean that you tried `C<typename T, typename A> m_children;` and got that error on that line? If so, well, I find the error confusing, but at least it's giving an error, as it should since `HasChildren` only takes one template parameter and neither `T` nor `A` is it - only `C` is.

Comment: did mean that, yes. Just in case you find it useful - I tried the other compiler, and for both with and without `typename` one of the errors was `error: unknown type name 'T'` for `T`. Anyways, many thanks once again for your help, you explained these things really well!

Comment: @AntonTretyakov You're welcome. I added an alternative if you prefer `HasChildren<std::vector<int>> hc; ` instead.

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I DIDN'T THINK ABOUT! I thought that maybe I would use `C::value_type` and `C::allocator_type` inside of the class when instantiating with `std::vector<int>`, but your solution is so much more elegant. Thanks again for broadening my applied knowledge!

Comment: @AntonTretyakov Cheers! Always glad when something I write helps! :-)